# Can't install python for arm on a x86 docker

Tags: python, docker, cross-compiling

OS: Linux.

I'm building & running a docker (based on ubuntu:18.04) that is cross-compiling for armhf, with python for arm installed on it.

Now, when I tried to build the same docker on a different pc, the installation of python's arm package caused errors.

running:

```
apt-get install python3.7:armhf python3.7-dev:armhf python3.7-minimal:armhf
```

produces the following:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.7-minimal.postinst: 46: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.7-minimal.postinst: /usr/bin/python3.7: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3.7-minimal:armhf (--configure):
 installed python3.7-minimal:armhf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up libexpat1-dev:armhf (2.2.5-3ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpython3.7-stdlib:armhf (3.7.5-2~18.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.7:armhf:
 python3.7:armhf depends on python3.7-minimal (= 3.7.5-2~18.04); however:
  Package python3.7-minimal:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.7:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.7-dev:armhf:
 python3.7-dev:armhf depends on python3.7 (= 3.7.5-2~18.04); however:
  Package python3.7:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.7-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpython3.7:armhf (3.7.5-2~18.04) ...
Setting up libpython3.7-dev:armhf (3.7.5-2~18.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.7-minimal:armhf
 python3.7:armhf
 python3.7-dev:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea what can be the problem, I'm struggling with it already a few days.
Maybe I'm missing some installation on the host??

Comment: Have you looked at this already:https://askubuntu.com/questions/914556/python-3-not-working?

Comment: apt-get install qemu-user-static (inside the docker, not only on the host) solved the problem. Strange that on a different pc it worked without qemu installation in the docker.

Comment: That pc is Mac? If so, docker desktop for Macs include things for cross-build first.